# Trying to read data from modbus RTU device in Pycharm using python and USB Converter

Tags: python, iot, communication, modbus, pymodbus

I have one modbus RTU based device. Parameters are Slave id 1 , Baud rate 9600, parity none, Stop bit 1, Read input register address 31001, counts 1, COM Port 4. The registers can be read successfully in ModScan32 as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: response rec from slab device in modscan32 software]

When I try to read the same register using pymodbus I can connect successfully (`Client.connect()` returns true) but I receive an error when running `Client.resd_input_registers` as shown in the image below:
[image: image is of code and its response]

Comment: Please add your code & error messages as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Agree with @Tagli but did take a quick look and correct spelling (`meathod` -> `method`) may help.

Comment: It might be the case that ModScan applies an offset of 1, i.e. reg. 1001 in ModScan is reg. 1000 in pymodbus.

Comment: I have done projects on Modbus. I can help you to read/write the data in modbus through your program. Post your code for help.